# Typo3 Content Elements missing in wizard

Tags: typo3

I have some content elements in a site package which I want to show up in the content element wizard as explained here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/ContentElementsWizard.html
Basically I have done the same as shown in the section "Create a new tab"

`Configuration\TsConfig\Page\ContentElement\All.tsconfig` is looking like this:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.mci.header = MCI
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.mci {
    elements {
        mci_home_banner {
            iconIdentifier = home-banner
            title = Home-Banner
            description = Banner der Startseite
            tt_content_defValues.CType = mci_home_banner
        }
        mci_home_banner_element {
            iconIdentifier = home-banner-element
            title = Home Banner Element
            description = Element im Starseitenbanner
            tt_content_defValues.CType = mci_home_banner_element
        }
    }
    show := addToList(mci_home_banner, mci_home_banner_element)
}
```

I reduced the code to just 2 elements. They are not shown at all, but are available over the dropdown, so I can switch to one of them after choosing another element.

This didn't work when created in 9.5 and still does not work after switching to version 11.5.10

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you included the TSconfig? Like here described in step 2? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/ContentElementsWizard.html

Comment: @Chris Yes, this file imports Configuration/TsConfig/Page/All.tsconfig and this again imports Configuration/TsConfig/Page/ContentElement/All.tsconfig. I guess otherwise the content elements wouldn't be available at all.

Answer (score 0):

@user414873 Did you try to add your custom elements to the "common" tab instead of your new one "mci"?

And did you try to use an existing icon identifier (e.g. "content-image" or an other one - see https://typo3.github.io/TYPO3.Icons/)? Just to make sure that there is no problem with your custom icons that prevents the elements from being displayed.

Does this minimal example work for you:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common {
    elements {
        mci_home_banner {
            iconIdentifier = content-image
            title = Home-Banner
            description = Banner der Startseite
            tt_content_defValues.CType = mci_home_banner
        }
    }
    show := addToList(mci_home_banner)
}
```

And I would doubt this:

> I guess otherwise the content elements wouldn't be available at all.

I suggest you check it's correctly included by using the "Info" module in your TYPO3 main menu. Then select the page where the content element should be included and switch the dropdown on top of the content area to "View TSconfig fields content". Now you can search for "wizards" and check if your element is included.